Accessing object field, sets List fields to null (Dart/Flutter)
I have an Event object that contains 3 lists of different enum types within it alongside other fields. One of the other fields is Also address.
Now the normal flow within my create method is that the object is received, another method is called to calculate the coordinates of the address and insert them into the Address address field, and then further creation methods are called to push data into the database.
This used to work without an issue up until recently, where now, when I update the coordinates field, all List fields lose all values that were stored inside.
EventDto.create method
static Future<Event?> create(Event event, File? coverImage) async {
  event.address.coordinates =
      await GeocodingService.addressToCoordinatesSecure(
    event.address,
  );

  debugPrint('Creating event...');

Rest of the method is irrelevant, so is not pasted.
The addressToCoordinatesSecure method
static Future<LatLng> addressToCoordinatesSecure(Address address) async {
    // URL encode the address
    String addressString = address.line1 +
        ', ' +
        address.city +
        ' ' +
        address.postalCode +
        ', ' +
        address.country;
    var encodedAddress = Uri.encodeComponent(addressString);

    // Replace with your Supabase Edge Function URL
    var url = Uri.parse(
        'https://ahhlfubdcyjqwsxieksc.supabase.co/functions/v1/get-coordinates');

    try {
      var response = await http.post(
        url,
        headers: {
          // Add a Bearer token using SupabaseAuthentication.getJWT() function
          'Authorization': 'Bearer ${await AuthenticationDto.getJWT()}',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: jsonEncode({'encodedAddress': encodedAddress}),
      );

      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        var data = json.decode(response.body) as List;
        if (data.isNotEmpty) {
          var lat = double.parse(data[0]['lat'].toString());
          var lon = double.parse(data[0]['lon'].toString());
          return LatLng(lat, lon);
        } else {
          throw Exception('No results found.');
        }
      } else {
        // Failed to load data and in a new line ErrorCode: ${response.statusCode}
        throw Exception(
            'Failed to load location data. \nErrorCode: ${response.statusCode}\n ${response.body}');
      }
    } catch (e) {
      throw Exception('Failed to load location data: $e');
    }
  }

When I set the breakpoint at the start of the create method, my List fields are there, after the coordinates are calculated they disappear (I am not altering the event object in the coordinate method, it doesn't even have access to the whole object).
I have attempted creating a copy of the address object before passing it to the geocoding method, as well as assigning the value first to a LatLng value, then assigning that to the event.address.coordinates in order to check if the issue is when I assign the value and not within the method. But, the values of the Lists are lost before I assign, they are lost somehow within the geocoding method and I have no clue how this is happening, because yet again, geocoding method doesn't have access to these lists...

In my opinion, it would be more useful to list how you defined the class Event instead of showing addressToCoordinatesSecure.  And maybe you could also include the return statement of the function create.

@DanR the problem is, I am not allowed to, but I can sort of explain, the object has let's say the following fields.
Address address;
List types;
List music_types;
When the DTO function receives the object, there are items in the list, after the call to the geolocation function, there is nothing inside of them. I can't imagine a way that this object could be made so that this should occur.

The problem might have something to do with how the list fields are initialized. Is your constructor defined approx. like this: Event({this.address, this.types, this.music_types})?

@DanR Hey man your comment actually helped me solve the error, went into the constructor and someone defined the lists, since they are optional parameters as const [] if they are initialized empty...
